# Any type of software like logcat to see error logs in Windos Xp os

Tags: windows, logging, error-handling, operating-system, windows-xp

Is there any type of software available which i can run to check for errors and abnormal behavior in ***Windows XP OS ***?

I know about The Application, Security, and System logs are displayed in the **Event Viewer window**.http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308427

Any other software available out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try :

http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/my_event_viewer.html

Accept & vote up the answer if it helps.